# PHP not storing values of selected checkbox inputs

Tags: php, session, checkbox

I am making a fake tool rental program using a database and PHP. This code gets information from a database, stores it in a variable called `$records` then creates a table with the information. I am trying to store the value from the column *tool_id* as the value for the checkboxes and pass the selected values to an array to make a cart but the array is always empty.

```
function drawTable($records) {
    $count = 0;
    $info = getToolInfo($records);

    echo "<table style='text-align:center;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid black'>";
    echo "<tr style='border:1px solid black'>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>Add to cart</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>Tool Name</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>Price</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>Availability</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>More info</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    foreach ($records as $record) {
        echo "<tr stlye='border:1px solid black'>";
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'><input type='checkbox' name='cart[]' value=".$record['tool_id']."></td>";
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>".$record['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>$".$record['price_total']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>".$record['status']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'><button tpye='button' onclick='var info=".json_encode($info[$count]).";displayPopup(info);'>More Info</button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $count++;
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

This code is where I try to access the array in another file called cart.php but the array is always empty.

```
session_start(); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

$cart = $_GET['cart'];

foreach ($cart as $tool) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $tool;
    echo $tool . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using form?

Comment: I tried putting it in <form></form> but it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to submit the form and store the value in session?

Comment: The problem is that the array is empty even in the same file before I try to access it in the cart.php file when I try to print_r() the array.

Answer (score 1):

Form does the work. Try the following code, where the table is wrapped in a form and the cart data will be sent to cart.php on submit.

```
echo "<form method='get' action='cart.php'><table style='text-align:center;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid black'>";
echo "<tr style='border:1px solid black'>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>Add to cart</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>Tool Name</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>Price</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>Availability</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>More info</td>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach($records as $record){
    echo "<tr style='border:1px solid black'>";

        echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'><input type='checkbox' name='cart[]' value=".$record['tool_id']."></td>";
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>".$record['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>$".$record['price_total']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>".$record['status']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'><button tpye='button' onclick='var info=".json_encode($info[$count]).";displayPopup(info);'>More Info</button></td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    $count++;
} 
 echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' value='Got to cart'></td></tr></table></form>";
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. For anyone looking at this  in the future my problem was I made a form each time I made a checkbox instead of putting them all in one form.

Answer (score 0):

if the cart checkbox field is not empty, use form ,add method = "POST" and action as cart.php. After submitting the form, get form fields by POST['cart'] in cart.php.